# Xcode 12 can't make sidebar wider

Tags: xcode, ui

In Xcode 12, my left and right sidebars have a tendency to get "stuck", and I can't pull them out all the way.

In this image, I would expect to be able to pull the left sidebar out further so I can read the text that is cut off. When I mouseover the sidebar border, the cursor changes to "resize" as expected, but then does nothing when I drag it out any further.  [image: A screenshot of Xcode that shows the problem I'm describing]

It seems to randomly work at times, but then go back to this behavior. Is there some setting that would fix this?

Comment: Have you fixed it? 